# Insta reels like functionality (using Exoplayer) with pagination and pull to refresh feature

Tags: android, kotlin, android-layout, android-recyclerview, android-viewpager2

I am working on an Insta reels like functionality (using Exoplayer) with pagination and pull to refresh feature. Can I get some references to implement this. Anything would be helpful. Thanks.

Comment: Please check this github project - https://github.com/vipulasri/JetInstagram, It may helps you.